# How to get controller and action name in OnActionExecuting?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Is it possible to figure out the currently executing controller/action in OnActionExecuting?

Comment: If any of these answers solved your problem you should consider making one as accepted.

Comment: @loyalflow let me be Navi here by saying "Hey! Listen! Mark an answer please"

Answer (score 120):

You could try the **[`ActionDescriptor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actiondescriptor(v=vs.108).aspx)** of the **[`ActionExecutingContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionexecutingcontext(v=vs.118).aspx)** as follows:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
   string actionName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
   string controllerName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName
   .....
   base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

Answer (score 41):

You can use [`ActionDescriptor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actiondescriptor%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) of [`ActionExecutingContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionexecutingcontext(v=vs.118).aspx)

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var descriptor = filterContext.ActionDescriptor;
    var actionName = descriptor.ActionName;
    var controllerName = descriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
    ......
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

Comment: My bad, this one isn't for net-core.

Answer (score 29):

For ASP.NET Core, Use the following,

```
var controllerName = ((ControllerBase)filterContext.Controller)
   .ControllerContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerName;
var actionName = ((ControllerBase)filterContext.Controller)
   .ControllerContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
```

Comment: simple.... solved issue

Answer (score 28):

You could look at the `RouteData`:

```
    Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"];
    Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["Action"];
```

Answer (score 15):

**ActionExecutingContext context** this is going to be your context....

```
var actionName = ((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActionDescriptor)context.ActionDescriptor).ActionName;
var controllerName = ((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActionDescriptor)context.ActionDescriptor).ControllerName;
```

Comment: This answer is for .Net-Core

Answer (score 1):

```
var controllerName = (string)routingValues["controller"];

var actionName = (string)routingValues["action"];
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you use Attributes (e.g. `ActionFilterAttribute`), if it so, you can get

- **action** name form attribute constructor:

  ```
      public CustomProfileAttribute([CallerMemberName]  string caller = null)
      {
          _actionName = caller;
      }
  ```
- **controller** name:

  ```
      public CustomProfileAttribute([CallerMemberName]  string caller = null)
      {
          _controllerName = context.Controller.ToString()
  ```
- or both **controller** and **action**:

  ```
      public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
      {
          var controllerAndAction = context.ActionDescriptor.DisplayName;
  ```

  but in such case you will have som ugly name like `controller.action (action)`