# Can I get strongly typed controller from `ActionExecutingContext`

Tags: asp.net-core

From [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18535241/how-to-get-controller-and-action-name-in-onactionexecuting) I see that it is possible to get the controller and action from `ActionExecutingContext`, but as strings.

Is there a chance to compare that in typed way like comparing to the controller class (e.g. `HomeController`) or the actual controller is not instanced at that point?

Comment: `filterContext.Controller` is the actual controller instance

Answer (score 0):

That question I referenced is for old asp net.
Fortunately, in aspnet core `ActionExecutingContext`, has a property `Controller` with the actual instance of the controller, and not a string.