# C# ASP.NET MVC : how to block override from the method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, web, model-view-controller

I am creating a session control on my project and I need help at the moment.

Basically, my `HomeController` inherits from `CustomController`.

`HomeController` manages the methods and `CustomController` runs before methods to check session info.

```
public class HomeController : CustomController
{
     public ActionResult Index()
     {                
     }
}

public class CustomController : Controller
{
    public OnActionExecuting()
    {
       // Check session
    }
}
```

My problem is, I do not want to check `Session` before `HomeController/Index` method. Is this possible?

Comment: `public static string Index()` is not an action method. `OnActionExecuting` don't get executed before index method

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the question. Thank you. (Its ActionResult)

Comment: The correct signature is `protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext` Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18535241/how-to-get-controller-and-action-name-in-onactionexecuting to understand how to get controller name and action name in `OnActionExecuting` and use it to skip session checking.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a custom attribute class as follows:

```
/// <summary>
/// Indicates whether session checking is enabled for an MVC action or controller.
/// </summary>
public class CheckSessionAttribute : Attribute
{
    public CheckSessionAttribute(bool enabled)
    {
        this.Enabled = enabled;
    }

    public bool Enabled { get; }
}
```

Then annotate the action method you want to exclude session checking with `[CheckSession(false)]`.

Lastly, include the following in the `OnActionExecuting` method of the base class:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    // Check if the CheckSession attribute is present and skip the session 
    // check if [CheckSession(false)] was explicitly provided.
    bool checkSession = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CheckSession), true)
        .OfType<CheckSession>()
        .Select(attr => attr.Enabled)
        .DefaultIfEmpty(true)
        .First();

    if (checkSession) 
    {
        // Check session
    }
}
```

This checks for the presence of the `[CheckSession(false)]` attribute and disables the session check in that case. In this way, you can configure the methods that should not check the session info simply by annotating them with the new attribute. This also makes it immediately clear that the session is not checked for that specific action.

Comment: This is excatly what am I looking for. Than you so much!